# driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'body') not working

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to open a new tab using `driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+'t')`
but the driver doesn't do anything after running this line. I think it's because the tag_name of the page isn't called 'body'. Is there any way to find out what it's called?

Script:

```
driver.find_element(By.NAME,"nickname").send_keys(username,str(x)+Keys.ENTER)
driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
```

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: If you can't find 'body', is that because you're already on an empty tab?

Comment: dude the actual problem is in the code, I want to open a new tab, but the driver can't find the element.

Comment: use driver.execute_script("window.open('about:blank', '_blank');");